# Is it possible to modify a selection on the fly?

Tags: jquery

Let's say

```
var d = jQuery('div');
```

If I use the .add() method:

```
d.add('p');

//result: Select all 'div' and 'p' in the document and d doesn't change
```

Now, is there a way of doing this (using other method, process) in a way that we can add an element temporary to a selection without changing the variable?

Let's say I want to select all paragraphs inside `d`, something like this:

```
jQuery('div p');
//This is what I want to achieve
```

Can I have something like:

```
d.somemethod('p')
```

without changing `d`, just temporarily, without having to write something like:

```
var dp = jQuery('div p');
```

Comment: Can't you just do? `var d = jQuery('div'); d = d.add(d.find("p"))`

Comment: Ok that's it:) Sorry, I am not a jQuery expert. This seems very basic:) If you answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the descendants of cached element from that element itself.

```
var d = jQuery('div'); 
d = d.add(d.find("p"));
```

Now `d` would be having all the div elements and its associated descendants matching the supplied selector.

Comment: Thank you:) I have to wait some minutes to accept:)

Comment: Just a little thing: As I don't want to change the variable can I modify the second line to just `d.add(d.find("p"));` ?

Comment: @viery365 You have to assign it to a different variable. Because, .add() will return the constructed result.

Comment: Ok:) but I imagine I still can use it on the fly:) It doesn't matter:) I got the point:) Thank you very much for your help:)